# Explain why the following collection of sets does not have a system of distinct representatives

Tags: graph-theory

> Explain why the following collection of sets does not have a system of distinct representatives:
>   $$
>   \mathrm{A}: \{5, 7\} \quad  
>   \mathrm{B}: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}  \quad
>   \mathrm{C}: \{4, 5\}  \quad
>   \mathrm{D}: \{6, 7\}  \\
>   \mathrm{E}: \{4, 7\}  \quad
>   \mathrm{F}: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7\}  \quad
>   \mathrm{G}: \{5, 7\}  \quad
> $$

Answer (score 2):

Try drawing a bipartite graph with vertices labelled $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G\}$ on one side and vertices labelled $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, with an edge joining a letter and a number if the number is in the set with that letter (e.g. $A$ has an edge to $5$ and to $7$).  Can you think of how [Hall's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) might apply to help you answer the question? (I assume you're using Hall's Theorem if you're doing systems of distinct representatives.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that you have a system of distinct representatives. The representatives for $A$ and $G$ must be $5$ and $7$ in one order or the other. That means that $7$ is unavailable to be the representative for $C$, so the representative for $C$ must be $4$. What can you say about the representatives for $D$ and $E$?